# Neutrino project in Tamil-Nadu India

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, neutrinos, biology

In [Tamil-Nadu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India-based_Neutrino_Observatory), the Indian government is going to start a neutrino project.

**Questions:**

1. Is it harmful for people who stay there?
2. Will this project affect any living beings?
3. Does it cause any pollution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie It is not a question about physics but it is about physicists and the environment. Having followed the stupid scare about black holes to be created at the LHC and the  end of the world I believe it is good to stomp this type of rumors  wherever they appear; and  health physics is still physics.

Comment: I object to the downvoting of this question and the assertion that it is not about physics. An astonishingly small fraction of human beings alive know what a neutrino is, and the history of physics is checkered by its close association with projectile and energy weapons. Mounish should be respected for his curiosity and deserves an answer.

Comment: I think there is no problem with the question .

Answer (score 5):

> [India-based Neutrino Observatory (](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India-based_Neutrino_Observatory)INO) is a particle physics research project under construction to primarily study atmospheric neutrinos in a 1,300 meters (4,300 ft) deep cave under Ino Peak near Theni, Tamil Nadu, India. This project is notable in that it is anticipated to provide a precise measurement of neutrino mixing parameters. The project is a multi-institute collaboration and one of the biggest experimental particle physics projects undertaken in India.

There is no more danger than in any other place on earth of the [same latitude](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0103286.pdf)  Atmospheric neutrinos arrive all the time and interact very weakly and that is why one needs experiments where all other interactions are  stopped and only neutrinos can be the reason of seeing a scatter.(deep caves).

> Is it harmful for people who stay there?

No, they will get the same atmospheric neutrinos whether the experiment is there or not

> Will this project affect any living beings?

Only for the better , as said in the other answer by freecharly

> Does it cause any pollution?

It is the polution happening when a university opens in a small town.

It is absolutely safe for the population.

Answer (score 2):

The neutrinos that are there anyway are  only detected in this project and pose no harm to anybody anyway. If one thinks hard about possible detrimental scenarios to the local population, it would be the additional need of electricity and water, new (educated) people arriving who are looking for housing, schooling, supplies, diversion, and possibly a minor earthquake if the underground cave unexpectedly collapses. But the latter seems to be extremely unlikely. The arrival of many people working on the project may well give a substantial boost to the local economy.