# How dangerous is a neutrino experiment near human habitation?

Tags: neutrinos, estimation, biology, laboratory-safety

I just read about people trying to capture neutrinos and study them. America has a lab in Antarctica and France deep under the ocean. Is it dangerous to conduct such an experiment where people live or near a river that people use for living? How dangerous could it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neutrino project in Tamil-Nadu India](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396852/)

Comment: Yeah I was asking for the same reason.I was asking generally so that some people wont say its a off topic.

Answer (score 7):

They are not really capturing neutrinos in the sense you seem to be thinking of, and they pose absolutely no danger to anyone.

There is a massive flux of neutrinos passing through the earth (and you personally) all the time. But they almost never interact: they just pass through as though the earth wasn't there. Neutrino detectors therefore have to be both very large ( to capture as many interactions as possible) and very isolated from noise (so that the few interactions they do see can be seen above the background radiation levels). Hence they tend to be under water, deep under ground, or under ice to reduce the background radiation they detect.

Comment: Thanks.I heard one such experiment done by Japan led to explosion.They said that it could be bcoz of high water pressure.Does this radiates any radio active particles??.Iam asking becoz the government is going to build one such lab near my habitation.

Comment: @aneeshcool The experiment you're talking about is called Super-Kamiokande (or Super-K for short). There was no explosion; rather, the detector bulbs broke because the water pressure was too high. But even if there had been an explosion, Super-K was literally just a water tank with some instruments attached. There is no radioactive material involved anywhere.

Comment: @aneeshcool And just to give you an idea of how little you need to worry: there are a trillion neutrinos, coming from the Sun, passing through your hand every second. You'll have an interaction with _one_ every _few years_, at most. You routinely get higher radiation doses than that from eating a single banana.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.Now Its clear that it has no harm.Does this experiment needs large amount of water bcoz as super-K exploded bcoz of high water pressure??.Will they draw large amount of water ?

Comment: @aneeshcool There was no explosion. Here's what happened: the instruments are surrounded by glass bulbs and kept in a vacuum. While the detector was being refilled, a few of those glass bulbs broke, due to the water pressure being slightly higher than normal. These experiments don't draw a large amount of water; they're filled up once, and then they run for years, until you have to do maintenance or upgrades, at which point the detector is emptied and refilled. But you really don't want to do that very often, as it messes with your data quality.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation.Its people around my area who are opposing the project saying the ill effects of the neutrino project.Now its clear to me.

Comment: @aneeshcool No problem! Neutrinos are one of the newer areas of physics research, so public awareness of them is understandably low.

Comment: yes.Unfortunately our scientist Dr.APJ Abdul kalam is not there to explain these things to our people.Hope you know this person.